# PowerMokito in android studio throwing errors

Tags: android, android-studio, mockito, powermock

I am trying to setup power mokito on my android project, to test static methods

I wrote these dependencies

```
        provided 'junit:junit:4.11'
        androidTestCompile ('junit:junit:4.11'){
        exclude module:"hamcrest-core"
        exclude module: "assertj-core"
            }

  //    provided 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.0.3-beta'
  //    androidTestCompile ('org.mockito:mockito-core:2.0.3-beta'){
  //    exclude module:"hamcrest-core"
  //    exclude module:"assertj-core"
  //    }
      provided 'org.powermock:powermock-mockito-release-full:1.4.9'
      androidTestCompile ('org.powermock:powermock-mockito-release-full:1.4.9'){
      exclude module : "hamcrest-core"
  //  exclude module : "mockito-all"
      exclude module: "assertj-core"
      exclude module: "objenesis"
       }
```

Then i wrote my test

```
import android.test.AndroidTestCase;

import com.myapp.IntentActions;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;



public class IntentActionsTest extends AndroidTestCase {


    @Test
    public void testIntentFilter() {

        //IntentActions class is a factory
        //for intent filters
        //I want to make sure that the filter is set up correctly
        //This is why I want to use PowerMockito
        mockStatic(IntentActions.class);

    }
}
```

The problem is when I run this test I get this error

```
java.lang.VerifyError: org/mockito/cglib/core/ReflectUtils
at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:167)
at org.mockito.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:217)
at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:109)
at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:105)
at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:70)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:68)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:50)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(MockCreator.java:100)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:58)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic(PowerMockito.java:70)
at com.myapp.tests.IntentActionsTest.testIntentFilter(IntentActionsTest.java:22)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
```

Comment: unfortunately i did not

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the problem, you are trying to run the PowerMockito test on Dalvik VM (Android Instrumentation Test). It is not possible, you should use the JVM to run the PowerMockito tests (Android Studio Unit Tests).

With the release 1.1 of the Android Studio was introduced the support for unit tests that can run on JVM.

So, to fix this issue you need to follow this tutorial (https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/unit-testing-support) to enable the unit tests to run on the JVM.